# Good reference for Cisco Resilient Ethernet Protocol

Tags: untagged

I have been trying to understand Cisco's Resilient Ethernet Protocol, but am unable to find a proper source to read from.

I checked the Cisco site and also their White Paper on REP. But none of them helped to understand REP clearly.

Googling was also of not much help, as all I got was explanation about configuration instructions and not on the protocol itself.

Can you guys point me to a good book or site, which explains Resilient Ethernet Protocol in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this Cisco page and it was much better in explaining REP. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/metro/me3400/software/release/12.2_40_se/configuration/guide/swrep.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can help you, but this is what I found:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/7600/ios/15S/configuration/guide/rep.html

OTOH this whitepaper looks okay to me:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps6568/ps6580/prod_white_paper0900aecd806ec6fa.pdf